Как влить запрос на слияние в GitHub одним коммитом?
Обычно, когда я вливаю запрос на слияние в свой репозиторий (например, от dependabot), я делаю это так:

Нажимаю Merge pull request:


Затем Confirm merge:



И в результате у меня получается два коммита:

Но, когда я создал запрос на слияние к чужому репозиторию и его влили, получился один коммит:

Как это делается?

У merge pull request справа есть треугольник

https://docs.github.com/ru/repositories/configuring-branches-and-merges-in-your-repository/configuring-pull-request-merges/about-merge-methods-on-github#squashing-your-merge-commits

@AlexeyTen, вижу, и какой пункт надо выбрать?

Squash and merge

Спасибо, на ближайшем запросе на слияние попробую. Можете написать как ответ?

https://docs.github.com/ru/pull-requests/collaborating-with-pull-requests/incorporating-changes-from-a-pull-request/merging-a-pull-request#merging-a-pull-request
Что бы был один коммит вам нужен пункт Squash and Merge.


Тут стоило бы упомянуть, что Squash and Merge  является потенциально деструктивной операцией, по итогом которой могут теряться куски истории правок.
